# How to select rows which have the biggest value of a column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know if my title is understandable or not, may be someone can help edit my title?

All I want to do is, for example:
I have a table like this
[image]

`Engineering` appears 5 times with different `article_category_abbr`, and I want to select only one row with the biggest value of num.
Here, it will be `Engineering-ENG-192`, and `Geriatrics&Gerontology` will be `Geriatrics&Gerontology-CLM-26`
But I don't know how to do it on the whole table using mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join your table to a subquery which finds the greatest `num` value for each `sc` group.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT sc, MAX(num) AS max_num
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY sc
) t2
    ON t1.sc = t2.sc AND
       t1.num = t2.max_num;
```

Comment: Am I not getting something or why wouldn't `SELECT sc, MAX(num) FROM table GROUP BY sc` work?

Comment: @lolbas That won't work if the OP also wants to select the `article_category_abbr` column value.  Then you would need to use a different approach.  If only the max num is desired, then your comment is correct.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Yes, the category is needed. I actually want to predict the label(`article_category_abbr`) for given attribute(`sc`) in a very simple way

Answer (score 1):

You can have a subquery that gets the largest value for each `sc` and the resulting rows will then be joined with the table itself based from two columns - `sc` and `num`.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  sc, MAX(num) AS Num
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY sc
        ) b ON a.sc = b.sc
            AND a.num = b.num
```

Here's a [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b6f43/2)

Answer (score 0):

USE `MAX` function and `GROUP BY` like this. [Here](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/Max-with-group-by.php) is more information.

```
SELECT myID, classTitle, subField, MAX(score) FROM myTable GROUP BY myID, classTitle, subField
```